# Help with inverse matrix problem? (Specific problem in description)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

\begin{equation} 
\text{If}
\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}
\text{=}\frac{1}{24}
\text{, solve }
\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}A\end{pmatrix}^{-1} - 120 \text{ }A^*
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

My attempt so far comes from the definition of an inverted matrix, namely

\begin{equation}
A^{-1} = \frac{A^{*}}{\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}}
\end{equation}

So substituting gets

\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}\frac{A^{*}}{\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}}\end{pmatrix}^{-1} - 120 \text{ }\frac{A^{-1}}{\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}}
\end{vmatrix}

Simplifying

\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{72}A^{*}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} - 5 \text{ }A^{-1}
\end{vmatrix}

Substituting using the inverse matrix definition again

\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{72}A^{-1}|A|\end{pmatrix}^{-1} - 5A^{-1}
\end{vmatrix}

Using

\begin{equation}
(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}\cdot A^{-1}
\end{equation}

And I get this?

\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{72}|A|\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}A^{-1}\end{pmatrix}^{-1} - 5A^{-1}
\end{vmatrix}

I think I went about this the wrong way completely, but I'm not getting any new ideas for now - woud appreciate any tips or hints regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention - A^{*} means an augmented matrix - I'm not sure if the notation is different in english math?

Comment: it seems slightly circular argument you are replacing $A^{-1}$ then again you are undoing change so you are back to beginning

Comment: @MRK Yes you're absolutely right...I was trying out different ways to solve this problem and ended up confused.

Answer (score 1):

Use the $A^{-1}$ only in second part or first part of the problem not both

\begin{equation}
A^{*} = \frac{1}{24}{A^{-1}}
\end{equation}

sub this where $A^*$ is in second part and don't change $A^{-1}$ until fully simplified

$=|\frac13 A^{-1} - 120 (\frac{1}{24} A^{-1})|$

$=|\frac13 A^{-1} - 5 A^{-1})|$

$=(\frac{-14}{3})^n |A^{-1}|$

$=(\frac{-14}{3})^n (24)$

Comment: I wasn't aware that (1/3A)^-1 = 1/3(A)^-1? I tried to test where you can just lift a constant out of this expression with a sample matrix, but the two weren't equivalent? Also, I'm kinda lost after the third step - how does it transform to (-14/3)^n (where does the power come from)? And after that step, how does det(A^-1) = 24? Again can you just make det(A^-1) = [det(A)]^-1?

Comment: @user1746848 please note $det(5A)=5^ndet(A)$ where A is $nxn$ matrix

Comment: @user1746848 $detA=det(\frac{1}{A^{-1}})$ and vice versa

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that up - it really helps. One thing that strikes me as odd is that we have never learnt either these properties in class, so I find it far fetched we should have to know this in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, I wanted to reiterate this question - \begin{equation}(\frac{1}{3}A)^{-1} = \frac{1}{3}(A)^{-1}\end{equation}? So you can just take the constant out?

Comment: @user1746848 may be there is an easier way then again the professor doesn't cover every formula they don't have that much time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19425/discussion-between-mrk-and-user1746848).